# why am i getting this error of Database Error: Permission Denied while retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase Android and loving it. Before I was able to retrieve the data. But Now that I am trying to check whether the same data exist. I am getting Database Error: Permission Denied.

Firebase Rules:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Code

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(ref != null){
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString().isEmpty()){
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        list.add(ds.getValue(Society_Address.class));

                    }

                    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(list);
                    rv_address.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using firebase real time database while the security rules in the question are for firestore.

You need to change firebase realtime database security rules to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```